# dealing with Dependencies for a multimodule Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I am working on a multi module maven project which have a parent POM packaging ,two war packaging module and Two jar packaging module,

```
parent
      mainWeb(Web)
           subweb(Web)
                 (subApi(Jar))optional true
           apI(Jar)
                 subApi(Jar)
```

We use Spring3 Hibernate4 Struts2

I use dependency tree to get the dependency details. But when I look the War generated there are same jars with different versions available. How can I find out the jars added by each dependency.

Comment: The `mvn dependency:tree` will show you which dependencies coming from which dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `maven-help-plugin:effective-pom` http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html, and `maven-dependency-plugin:list` http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks for the early replay. i have tried `mvn help:effective-pom -Dplugin=help -Ddetail=true` if am not wrong it gives the same details as dependency tree. what i want is for example when i remove the dependency of commons-beanutils. the jar is being added by display-tag jar. if i excluded from it. again it is added by struts-menu jar.

Comment: Is there any way to get the dependent jars of a jar ?